# Keepalived split brain issue

Tags: firewalld, keepalived

I have issue with keepalived on Oracle Linux 8. The VIP is assigned to both nodes and both nodes are in MASTER mode.

**My keepalived configuration is:**

Node 1 cat /etc/keepalived/keepalived.conf

```
global_defs {
  vrrp_priority -20
  checker_priority -19
  script_user root
}

vrrp_script chk_haproxy {
  script "/usr/bin/killall -0 haproxy" # check the haproxy process
  interval 2 # every 2 seconds
  weight 2 # add 2 points if OK
  timeout 3
  fall 3
}

vrrp_instance VI_1 {
  interface ens192 # interface to monitor
  state BACKUP # MASTER on haproxy1, BACKUP on haproxy2
  nopreempt
  virtual_router_id 52
  priority 101 # 101 on haproxy1, 100 on haproxy2
  virtual_ipaddress {
   VIP_adcat /vardress  # virtual ip address
  }
  track_script {
    chk_haproxy
  }
}
```

Node 2 cat /etc/keepalived/keepalived.conf

```
global_defs {
  vrrp_priority -20
  checker_priority -19
  script_user root
}

vrrp_script chk_haproxy {
  script "/usr/bin/killall -0 haproxy" # check the haproxy process
  interval 2 # every 2 seconds
  weight 2 # add 2 points if OK
  timeout 3
  fall 3
}

vrrp_instance VI_1 {
  interface ens192 # interface to monitor
  state BACKUP # MASTER on haproxy1, BACKUP on haproxy2
  nopreempt
  virtual_router_id 52
  priority 100 # 101 on haproxy1, 100 on haproxy2
  virtual_ipaddress {
   VIP_adress  # virtual ip address
  }
  track_script {
    chk_haproxy
  }
}
```

I have added rules to firewall:

firewall-cmd --list-all

```
public (active)
  target: default
  icmp-block-inversion: no
  interfaces: ens192
  sources: here are ip addreses of both nodes
  services: cockpit dhcpv6-client ssh
  ports: 3306/tcp 3305/tcp
  protocols:
  forward: no
  masquerade: no
  forward-ports:
  source-ports:
  icmp-blocks:
  rich rules:
   rule family="ipv4" destination address="224.1.0.0/16" accept
   rule family="ipv4" destination address="224.0.0.18" protocol value="ip" accept
   rule protocol value="vrrp" accept
```

When I disable firewalld everything is ok and working, but with started firewalld I get both nodes with VIP.

In the logs I can find log: Keepalived_vrrp[1077307]: (VI_1) Receive advertisement timeout

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

If when firewall is down it`s working, but when firewall is up it`s not, than is the issue with firewall.

Can you check this via tcpdump.

But this same issue of keepalived and firewall is in example here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12908701/keepalived-works-well-without-iptables

tested you resolve from this questions?

Comment: I have saw that earlier and tried but still not working. RHEL 8/oracle linux 8 does not use classic ip tables.

Comment: But I see on you firewall you have only destination address.. and not port 51. Please add rules with source address for input traffic, and port 51 TCP for source from hostA and hostB, and check

Comment: Why port 51? I have added port 51, but that didn't help.